# Measure not filtering lastdate

Tags: powerbi, dax

I can't get Power BI to filter by last date in file.

When I try:

```
test = CALCULATE(
    DISTINCT(table[Date]),
    filter(
        all(table[Date]),
        table[Date] =  date(2019,3,1)
    )
)
```

It returns me the date March 1, 2019.

But if I use

```
test = CALCULATE(
    DISTINCT(tabela_ajustada[Data]),
    filter(
        all(tabela_ajustada[Data]),
        tabela_ajustada[Data] =  LASTDATE(tabela_ajustada[Data])
    )
)
```

It won't work, it's not filtering at all, so I get an error because it returns multiple values and I can't add to the card.

table[Date] has multiple non unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
test = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCT(tabela_ajustada[Data]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(tabela_ajustada[Data]),
        tabela_ajustada[Data] =  LASTDATE ( ALL ( tabela_ajustada[Data] ) )
    )
)
```

Comment: It worked with max(table[Date]) insteade of lastdate(table[Date])). Your measure returned empty.